# inner join multiple rows into one

Tags: php, mysql

I have to tables, users and user_services.

```
users table -> uid name email
user_services -> service_id uid
```

now when I do inner join like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN user_services ON users.u_id=user_services.user_id  WHERE u_id = '76'
```

I got 4 rows because user has 4 services() and that is ok.

**My question is how to have only one row and in last column (service_id) to have**:

```
array(1,2,3,4) / or just 1,2,3,4
```

If I do `group by u_id` I will get only one row, but in last column I will get only first service id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you to get the result .

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_services.service_id)  FROM users INNER JOIN user_services ON users.u_id=user_services.user_id  WHERE u_id = '76' group by users.u_id;
```